# A easy question on projection operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $B(H)$ be all the bounded linear operators on $H$, for arbitrary $T\in B(H)$, if $\{P_{i}\}$ is an increasing net of finite-rank projection, can we conclude $P_{i}TP_{i} \rightarrow T$ in norm topology or , even, in strong operator topology?

Comment: You would need $P_i \to 1$ pointwise at the very least

Answer (score 2):

If $P_i\to I$ in the strong operator topology, then
$$
\|(P_iTP_i-T)h\|=\|P_iTP_ih-Th\|\leq\|P_iTP_i-P_iTh\|+\|P_iTh-Th\|\\
\leq\|P_i\|\,\|T\|\,\|(P_i-I)h\|+\|(P_i-I)Th\|\\
\leq\|T\|\,\|(P_i-I)h\|+\|(P_i-I)Th\|\to0
$$
In the norm topology it is never true for infinite-dimensional $H$: just take $T=I$, and then
$$
\|P_iTP_i-T\|=\|P_i-I\|=1.
$$